# Could it be illegal for an individual in USA to hire a software developer in Syria or Venezuela for short project?

Tags: united-states, sanctions

This question is about an individual in USA hiring a software developer for a short project through a site such as [guru.com](https://www.guru.com/) or [freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com/).

Considering that U.S. has sanctions on Venezuela (described [here](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Sanctions/Pages/faq_other.aspx#venezuela)) and Syria (described [here](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Sanctions/Pages/faq_other.aspx#syria_whole)), could it be illegal to hire someone who is living in either of those countries?

Comment: _"Considering that U.S. has sanctions on Syria and Venezuela"_ What specific sanctions are you referring to?

Comment: @guest271314, I have updated the question with links to treasury.gov documentation about the sanctions.

Comment: It really seems you answered your own question by citing the specific sanctions.  What point are you unclear on?

Comment: The Venezuelan sanctions revolve around providing loans/financing/property/etc to the Venezuelan government, not individual citizens. Syria seems to be different and I would avoid hiring/contracting to individuals there.

Comment: [Related](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/72666/6854)